# Python - datetime.now() returns incorrect time

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to store in my data base the time stamp of an operation. The problem is that the time that I get from `datetime.datetime.now()`is incorrect (I guess it's due to time zone). I tried getting the value in the terminal using python and got the correct result.

```
import datetime 
datetime.datetime.now()//correct time
```

However if I print the result during problem execution the output is incorrect, the result is two hours earlier.

Why is it like that, that the terminal gives me the correct time but the program instance isn't, how can I get the correct time in my program?

**Edit:**
The date time from the terminal:

```
2018-08-30 17:41:04.413187
```

The date time from program instance:

```
2018-08-30 14:42:31.761310
```

**Edit:**

I noticed that I have this warning when I run the program.

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Policy.last_update received a naive datetime (2018-08-30 15:16:23.689896) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Comment: What is the result of `datetime.datetime.now().tzinfo` in both the terminal and in a script? Do you have more than one version of python installed?

Comment: well, in terminal I get **datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'tz_info'**

Comment: It returns None

Comment: In script I also get None

Comment: Huh, and they are both being run on the same machine? And `import sys; sys.version` are the same? Could you give an example of both datetimes in the terminal and in the script as well as the outputs of `sys.version`

Comment: yes, both run on the same machine. python version is 2.7.1.

Comment: from terminal: '2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]'

from program: 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]

Comment: Edit your original post and put the two datetimes in

Comment: Well this is odd. What about a different package (that handles timezones correctly) like arrow. `$pip install arrow` and then try `import arrow; print(arrow.now(), arrow.utcnow(), sep='\n\n')`

Comment: What OS do you run the script on? 
How do you run the script in the command line and otherwise (if bash, then what is timezone setup in bash?)?

Comment: @Keselme, are you sure you typed `datetime.datetime.now().tzinfo` and not `datetime.datetime.now().tz_info`?

Comment: @sophros I use MacOS. In command line I just typed **python** then *import datetime** and then **datetime.datetime.now()**

Comment: @walrus yes, I checked that I typed that correctly.

Comment: @sophros how do I check what time zone in bash?

Comment: @Keselme OK, good to rule that out

Comment: @FHTMitchell after installing arrow this is the output I got
(<Arrow [2018-08-30T15:08:29.875328+00:00]>, <Arrow [2018-08-30T15:08:29.875397+00:00]>)

Comment: Are you in UTC+0? I doubt it since the western Europe is on Summer time

Answer (score 6):

Try this adjusting the number of hours depending on the timezone you are:

```
import datetime 

datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import pytz
import datetime

timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz = timezone)
```

install pytz: `pip install pytz`

get all timezones: `print(pytz.all_timezones)`

Comment: Please do not recommend pytz anymore: It is broken, deprecated and adds an external dependency. Use zoneinfo instead.