# Wrong time on Windows 10

Tags: python, time, windows-10

I am using software that uses python to connect to Twitter API.

Twitter API won't connect if the time set on my PC is wrong.'

The problem is that Windows 10 time does not affect what python is reading. I can change windows time and timezone but python always shows me the wrong time.

I double-checked the BIOS time and its correct, and also I followed this instructions

https://windowsreport.com/wrong-time-on-windows-clock-fix/

But python still giving me the wrong time.

If I input this

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

local = datetime.now()
print("Local:", local.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

Always is giving me one hour less than the bios time.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a Daylight Saving Time (aka Summer Time) issue. Is your computer configured correctly? It's not a Python issue.

Comment: The Bios time is only used just after a boot.  After that Windows will check with a time server and sync with that.  Right-click on the clock in the status bar and go to Settings.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52114630/12130308

Or try:

1. [Sync Now] on Windows 10 [Settings->Date & Time]
2. Check your time-zone
3. Maybe daylight saving problem?

Comment: I switched to automatic and tried changing on and off the daylight saving time option. but the problem still there. Maybe there is a way to change the daylight saving option using command prompt ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the time manually. Maybe you should include Time-zone in your code.

Comment: I tried to do it manually as well. But always there is one hour difference ... The problem is that the software I am using, called touchdesigner, uses python but I cannot modify the code.  To test if there was a problem with the software itself,  I tried using externally this python code to check the time. And results with the same error, also I tried the same code with the w3schools online editor, and still giving the wrong time

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a timezone issue. What is your local timezone? Do you know if it had some recent changes?

For example, several years ago Europe/Moscow timezone was switched between GMT+3 and GMT+4 - first the government decided to disable DST (daylight saving time) and fixed timezone to GMT+4, then they changed their mind and fixed timezone to GMT+3. All these changes resulted in timezone being inconsistent on some devices with older firmware.
So, if your timezone had some changes recently, then you may need to update timezone information either in Python or in Windows.

Another possible reason is that Linux/MacOS store UTC time in BIOS by default, and Windows stores local time in BIOS. This results in a mess when using several OSes on the same computer. Although I don't think it could influence just Python in Windows without affecting Windows itself.

You can try this:

```
import time
ts = time.time()  # should be a UTC timestamp in seconds since epoch
utc = time.gmtime(ts)
local = time.localtime(ts)
print('utc', utc)
print('loc', local)
```

What will be the difference between the two resulting structures? Is it consistent with your local timezone?

Comment: I am using windows 10, and the timezone is UTC+00 Lisbon, London. I just typed this code and returns me 1:51 in both utc and local but the actual time is 2:51.

Comment: if I activate the daylight saving , then it shows 3:51

Comment: my device is quite new, is only 1 year old ... I updated drivers and also windows update, I also tried to setup the timezone using tzutil command